# Writing Vectors As A Linear Combination Of Other Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've been tangled with a section from a question :

In the vector space of  **$P_3(R)$** given a group of vectors :

$$S= \{u_1=1+t+t^2 , u_2=2+3t+3t^2 , u_3=2+6t-t^2 , u_4=1-2t+2t^2+5t^3\}$$

I have managed to check whether they are linearly independent or not and found the basis and the dimension of $S$

$$B_S=\{(1,0,0,1),(0,1,0,1),(0,0,1,-1)\}$$
$${\operatorname{dim}_S=3}$$

and what is left is to type all the vectors that belong to S as a combination for the basis i found , kind of stuck there , any suggestions ?

Comment: For each $U_i$, write $U_i= \alpha_1 (1,0,0,1) + \alpha_2 (0,1,0,1) + \alpha_3 (0,0,1,-1)$. You get four equations, one of which would be redundant if dimension is 3. Solve for $\alpha_i's$. By the way, I don't think that the dimension is 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $S$ is equal to$$\{a+bt+ct^2+dt^3\mid a+b=c+d\}.$$This is a $3$-dimensional vector subspace of, which contains $1+t^3$, $t+t^3$, and $t^2-t^3$, which are the elements of your basis.

Answer (score 1):

Given a polynomial $p \in P_3(R)$, where $p(x) =a +bx + cx^2 + dx^3$.

From the coefficient of $1, x, x^2$, we can conclude that $$p(x) = a(1+x^3) + b(x+x^3) + c(x^2-x^3)$$